# Test Class for a class which is called in a Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a Apex class which is called in a trigger. I have written a test class but my code coverage is only 15%. I have tried multiple approaches but all in vain. Please assist me to do the changes.

**APEX CLASS:**

```
public class BQDetailsUpdateClass {

    public static void createBQDetails(Product2 product){
               if(product.Vertical__c != null && product.Vertical__c.equals('Credit Cards') && product.Approval_Status__c != null && product.Approval_Status__c.equals('Approved')) {
                List<PriceBookEntry> pbes = [Select Id,UnitPrice,CurrencyIsoCode,BQ_Detail__c from PriceBookEntry where Product2Id =: product.Id and Pricebook2Id != '01s41000007uZohAAE' and IsActive = true];
                for(PriceBookEntry pbe : pbes) {
                    BQ_Detail__c bqd = new BQ_Detail__c();
                    if(product.Lightbox_Pricing__c) {
                        bqd.Product__c = product.Id;
                        bqd.Vantage_Pricing__c = true;
                        bqd.Price__c = pbe.UnitPrice;
                        bqd.CurrencyIsoCode = pbe.CurrencyIsoCode;
                    } else {
                        bqd.Product__c = product.Id;
                        bqd.Price__c = pbe.UnitPrice;
                        bqd.CurrencyIsoCode = pbe.CurrencyIsoCode;
                    }
                    bqd.Start_Date__c = product.Activated_Start_Date__c;
                    bqd.End_Date__c = product.Activated_End_Date__c;
                    bqd.Eligible_for_BQ__c = true;
                    if(String.IsBlank(pbe.BQ_Detail__c)) {  
                        insert bqd;
                        pbe.BQ_Detail__c = bqd.Id;
                        update pbe;
                    } else {
                        bqd.Id = pbe.BQ_Detail__c;
                        update bqd;
                    }
                    
                }
                List<Product_Offering__c> poffers = [Select Id ,CurrencyIsoCode, Offer_Name__c ,BQ_Detail__c,List_Price__c, End_Date__c, Start_Date__c from Product_Offering__c where Product__c =: product.Id and Active__c = true];
                
                for(Product_Offering__c poffer : poffers) {
                    BQ_Detail__c bqd = new BQ_Detail__c();
                    bqd.Product__c = product.Id;
                    bqd.Price__c = poffer.List_Price__c;
                    bqd.CurrencyIsoCode = poffer.CurrencyIsoCode;
                    bqd.Offer_Name__c = poffer.Offer_Name__c;
                    bqd.Start_Date__c = poffer.Start_Date__c;
                    bqd.End_Date__c = poffer.End_Date__c;
                    bqd.Eligible_for_BQ__c = true;
                    if(String.IsBlank(poffer.BQ_Detail__c)) {
                        insert bqd;
                        poffer.BQ_Detail__c = bqd.Id;
                        update poffer;
                    } else {
                        bqd.Id = poffer.BQ_Detail__c;
                        update bqd;
                    }
                }
              }
    }
}
```

**TEST CLASS**

```
@isTest

public class BQDetailsUpdateClassTest_PK {
      
    @isTest
    public static void lightboxTrue(){
        Product2 prod = new Product2(); 
        prod.Name = 'Test ck';
        prod.Description = 'Test';
        prod.Vertical__c = 'Credit Cards';
        prod.Lightbox_Pricing__c = true;
        prod.IsActive = true;
        prod.Approval_Status__c='Approved';
        prod.Activated_Start_Date__c=System.today();
        prod.Activated_End_Date__c=System.today();
        insert prod;  
        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry();
        BQ_Detail__c bqd1 = new BQ_Detail__c();        
        bqd1.Product__c=prod.Id;        
        bqd1.Price__c=pbe.UnitPrice;
        bqd1.Vantage_Pricing__c=true;
        bqd1.CurrencyIsoCode=pbe.CurrencyIsoCode;
        insert bqd1; 
        
        //PricebookEntry updatePriceBookEntry = new PricebookEntry( id=standardPrice.Id,UnitPrice = 30.00);
        //update updatePriceBookEntry;
        
        BQDetailsUpdateClass.createBQDetails(prod);
        
    }
    
    @isTest
    public static void lightboxFalse(){
        Product2 prod = new Product2(); 
        prod.Name = 'Test ck';
        prod.Description = 'Test';
        prod.Vertical__c = 'Credit Cards';
        prod.Lightbox_Pricing__c = false;
        prod.IsActive = true;
        prod.Approval_Status__c='Approved';
        prod.Activated_Start_Date__c=System.today();
        prod.Activated_End_Date__c=System.today();
        insert prod;  
        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry();
        BQ_Detail__c bqd1 = new BQ_Detail__c();        
        bqd1.Product__c=prod.Id;        
        bqd1.Price__c=pbe.UnitPrice;
        bqd1.CurrencyIsoCode=pbe.CurrencyIsoCode;
        insert bqd1; 
        
        //PricebookEntry updatePriceBookEntry = new PricebookEntry( id=standardPrice.Id,UnitPrice = 30.00);
        //update updatePriceBookEntry;
        
        BQDetailsUpdateClass.createBQDetails(prod);
        
    }
    
    
    
    @isTest
    public static void Test2(){
        Product2 prod = new Product2();
        prod.Name = 'Test ck';
        prod.Description = 'Test';
        prod.Vertical__c = 'Credit Cards';
        prod.Lightbox_Pricing__c = true;
        prod.IsActive = true;
        prod.Approval_Status__c='Approved';
        prod.Activated_Start_Date__c=System.today();
        prod.Activated_End_Date__c=System.today();
        insert prod;
        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry();
        Product_Offering__c po= new Product_Offering__c();
        po.List_Price__c=26;
        po.CurrencyIsoCode=prod.CurrencyIsoCode;
        po.BQ_Detail__c ='a1v02000000Nril';
        insert po;
        BQ_Detail__c bqd2 = new BQ_Detail__c();
        bqd2.Product__c=prod.Id;
        bqd2.Price__c=po.List_Price__c;
        bqd2.Offer_Name__c = po.Offer_Name__c;
        bqd2.CurrencyIsoCode = po.CurrencyIsoCode;
        bqd2.Start_Date__c = po.Start_Date__c;
        bqd2.End_Date__c = po.End_Date__c;
        bqd2.Eligible_for_BQ__c = true;
        insert bqd2;
        BQDetailsUpdateClass.createBQDetails(prod);
        
    }
    
    @isTest
    public static void updatePricebook(){
        Product2 prod = new Product2();
        prod.Name = 'Test ck';
        prod.Description = 'Test';
        prod.Vertical__c = 'Credit Cards';
        prod.Lightbox_Pricing__c = true;
        prod.IsActive = true;
        prod.Approval_Status__c='Approved';
        prod.Activated_Start_Date__c=System.today();
        prod.Activated_End_Date__c=System.today();
        insert prod;
        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry();
        pbe.UnitPrice = 2;
        pbe.Product2Id = prod.id;
        pbe.Pricebook2Id = '01s41000007uZohAAE';
        insert pbe;
        BQ_Detail__c bqd2 = new BQ_Detail__c();
        bqd2.Start_Date__c = prod.Activated_Start_Date__c;
        bqd2.End_Date__c = prod.Activated_End_Date__c;
        bqd2.Eligible_for_BQ__c = true;
        pbe.BQ_Detail__c = null;
        insert bqd2;
        pbe.BQ_Detail__c = bqd2.Id;
        update pbe;
        BQDetailsUpdateClass.createBQDetails(prod);
        
    }
    
    @isTest
    public static void updateBqd1(){
        Product2 prod = new Product2();
        prod.Name = 'Test ck';
        prod.Description = 'Test';
        prod.Vertical__c = 'Credit Cards';
        prod.Lightbox_Pricing__c = true;
        prod.IsActive = true;
        prod.Approval_Status__c='Approved';
        prod.Activated_Start_Date__c=System.today();
        prod.Activated_End_Date__c=System.today();
        insert prod;
        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry();
        pbe.UnitPrice = 2;
        pbe.Product2Id = prod.id;
        pbe.Pricebook2Id = '01s41000007uZohAAE';
        insert pbe;
        BQ_Detail__c bqd2 = new BQ_Detail__c();
        bqd2.Start_Date__c = prod.Activated_Start_Date__c;
        bqd2.End_Date__c = prod.Activated_End_Date__c;
        bqd2.Eligible_for_BQ__c = true;
        pbe.BQ_Detail__c = 'a1v02000000NWXoAAO';
        insert bqd2;
        bqd2.Id= pbe.BQ_Detail__c;
        update bqd2;
        BQDetailsUpdateClass.createBQDetails(prod);
        
    }
    
    @isTest
    public static void updateProductoffer(){
        Product2 prod = new Product2();
        prod.Name = 'Test ck';
        prod.Description = 'Test';
        prod.Vertical__c = 'Credit Cards';
        prod.Lightbox_Pricing__c = true;
        prod.IsActive = true;
        prod.Approval_Status__c='Approved';
        prod.Activated_Start_Date__c=System.today();
        prod.Activated_End_Date__c=System.today();
        insert prod;
        Product_Offering__c po= new Product_Offering__c();
        po.List_Price__c=26;
        po.CurrencyIsoCode=prod.CurrencyIsoCode;
        po.BQ_Detail__c ='a1v02000000Nril';
        insert po; 
        BQ_Detail__c bqd2 = new BQ_Detail__c();
        bqd2.Product__c = prod.id;
        bqd2.Price__c = po.List_Price__c;
        bqd2.CurrencyIsoCode = po.CurrencyIsoCode;
        bqd2.Offer_Name__c = po.Offer_Name__c;
        bqd2.Start_Date__c = po.Start_Date__c;
        bqd2.End_Date__c = po.End_Date__c;
        bqd2.Eligible_for_BQ__c = true;
        po.BQ_Detail__c = null;
        insert bqd2;
        po.BQ_Detail__c = bqd2.Id;
        update po;
        BQDetailsUpdateClass.createBQDetails(prod);
        
    }
    
    @isTest
    public static void updateBqd2(){
        Product2 prod = new Product2();
        prod.Name = 'Test ck';
        prod.Description = 'Test';
        prod.Vertical__c = 'Credit Cards';
        prod.Lightbox_Pricing__c = true;
        prod.IsActive = true;
        prod.Approval_Status__c='Approved';
        prod.Activated_Start_Date__c=System.today();
        prod.Activated_End_Date__c=System.today();
        insert prod;
        Product_Offering__c po= new Product_Offering__c();
        po.List_Price__c=26;
        po.CurrencyIsoCode=prod.CurrencyIsoCode;
        po.BQ_Detail__c ='a1v02000000Nril';
        insert po; 
        BQ_Detail__c bqd2 = new BQ_Detail__c();
        bqd2.Product__c = prod.id;
        bqd2.Price__c = po.List_Price__c;
        bqd2.CurrencyIsoCode = po.CurrencyIsoCode;
        bqd2.Offer_Name__c = po.Offer_Name__c;
        bqd2.Start_Date__c = po.Start_Date__c;
        bqd2.End_Date__c = po.End_Date__c;
        bqd2.Eligible_for_BQ__c = true;
        insert bqd2;
        bqd2.Id = po.BQ_Detail__c;
        update bqd2;
        BQDetailsUpdateClass.createBQDetails(prod);
        
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Mahesh

Comment: You are responsible for creating basically _all_ of the data that your test needs. In this case, you're not creating any appropriate `PricebookEntry` records. You're hard-coding Ids (which is never a good idea), and for the few tests where you do create a PBE, you're explicitly using the PricebookId that the query in your SUT (system under test, i.e. the class you're trying to test) is filtering out.

Comment: The other point to note is that just because this code is normally invoked from within a trigger doesn't mean you can only test it in the context of a trigger. Personally I would write a test that directly invokes the logic without inserting data into the database if at all possible (though clearly if the code queries data in the database you need to make sure that is available or you need to mock out the querying).

Comment: I have inserted PricebookEntry record and also i have removed hardcoded id. Still my code coverage is same.                                                                               
   @isTest
    public static void lightboxTrue(){
   ...  
        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry();
        pbe.UnitPrice = 2;
        pbe.Product2Id = prod.id;
        pbe.Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
        pbe.IsActive = true;
        insert pbe;        
    }

Comment: `Pricebook2Id != '01s41000007uZohAAE'`  do not put hardcoded Pricebook2Ids in code. If there is some Pricebook2 to ignore, query for it by name